# jQuery validation and accept="image/*"

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I am working on a form, which has some text fields and following input element:

```
<input class='ignore' name='photo' id='photo' type='file' accept="image/*"/>
```

Also, I have scripts: jQuery, jQueryUI, jQuery validation, jQuery unobtrusive and  unobtrusive-ajax. I think it is most common set of jQuery scripts.

But I have met very painful problem. This input always marked as error, after I select image there. This is true for all browser as well.

I tried to add

```
$("#application-form").validate({
   ignore: ".ignore"
})
```

But this didn't help.
So, I really wondered how to handle this issue...

PS. I also tried to use some kind of workaround, by adding this script instead of input element:

```
$("#photo-container").html("<input class='ignore' name='photo' id='photo' type='file' accept='image/*'/>   ");
```

but got exactly the same behavior

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your jQuery as it stands.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Solved!

```
    $("#photo").rules("add", {
        accept: "jpg|jpeg|png|ico|bmp"
    });
```

Answer (score 4):

This worked well in my case.

```
   $("#application-form").validate({
    rules: {
        photo: {
            required: true,
            extension: "jpg|jpeg|png|ico|bmp"
        }
    },
    messages: {
        photo: {
            required: "Please upload file.",
            extension: "Please upload file in these format only (jpg, jpeg, png, ico, bmp)."
        }
    },
    errorElement: "span",
    errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
        error.addClass("help-block");
        if (element.prop("type") === "checkbox") {
            error.insertAfter(element.parent("label"));
        } else {
            error.insertAfter(element);
        }
    },
    submitHandler: function () {
        //do your stuff here
    }
});
```

Note: You'll have to include `additional-methods.js` because the `extension` methods is not included in the core validate plugin.

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.16.0/additional-methods.js"></script>
```